# How to to extract the year from JSON date using jq

Tags: json, command-line, jq

I have a bunch of JSON with dates in ISO format. How can I print only the year component of the date?

```sh
$ echo '{"createdDate": "2005-09-28T16:34:40Z"}' | jq '{ createdYear: ??? }'
{
  "createdYear": "2005"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just:

```
{createdYear: .createdDate[0:4]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `strptime` to convert date string to date object and then `strftime` to format the date:

```sh
$ echo '{"createdDate": "2005-09-28T16:34:40Z"}' |
    jq '
       { createdYear: .createdDate
           | strptime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
           | strftime("%Y") }'
{
  "createdYear": "2005"
}
```