# AWS Kinesis Firehose - dynamic partitioning by timestamp other than epoch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose, aws-event-bridge

My `Firehose` reads from `Eventbridge` events that look something like:

```
{
  "detail": {
    "key1": "some value",
    "key2": "some value",
    "Timestamp": "2022-01-21T19:01:05Z"
  }
}
```

I'd like to perform dynamic partition when saving the events to files in `s3`.
I tried to extract the year like so:

```
.detail.Timestamp| strftime("%Y")
```

I know this would have worked if `Timestamp` field was given in the `epoch` format, but now I get the error (saved to a file by `firehose`):

```
{
  . . .
  "errorCode": "DynamicPartitioning.MetadataExtractionFailed",
  "errorMessage": "strftime/1 requires parsed datetime inputs",
  . . .
}
```

What's the right syntax to extract year (and other time parts) from a timestamp like my events contain?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I realized that the way to select keys to be used for partitioning is to use `jq` syntax.
So using `| strftime("%Y")` is the way to extract year from *epoch* time. To extract it from my time format, I needed to add another step of `| strptime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")`.

The full solution would be: `.detail.Timestamp| strptime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")| strftime("%Y")`.

After having understood that this is actually `jq`, the answer from here [How to to extract the year from JSON date using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66013045/how-to-to-extract-the-year-from-json-date-using-jq) is what completed the puzzle for me.